# Conditional probabilities, how to set up and evaluate using existing knowledge.

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I am presented with this problem:

> The probability of a program having a bug and crashing is 0.2. There
>   are two testing procedures that can be used to detect bugs. Each testing procedure utilizes 50% of the code and the first one detects 50% of all bugs occurring in its code area. The second testing procedure can detect 30% of the bugs occurring in its code area. Both procedures overlap in their evaluation on 50% of the code that they use during an evaluation and can therefore
>   both detect the same bugs if they occur in this area (but do so in different, independent ways). Neither one of the tests will erroneously produce a bug warning and it is assumed that a major bug is equally likely in all code areas (none of these assumptions is assumed to be realistic for real software testing). How high is the probability that a program does not have a major bug if it passes both testing procedures?

From what I understand, I am trying to find out the following probability and have the following knowledge.

$$
P(C)=0.2\\P(T_{1_{pass}})=0.5*0.5=0.25\\P(T_{2_{pass}})=0.5*0.3=0.15\\
P(\lnot C\mid T_{1_{pass}}\land T_{2_{pass}})=\frac{P(T_{1_{pass}}\land T_{2_{pass}}\mid \lnot C)P(\lnot C)}{P(T_{1_{pass}}\land T_{2_{pass}})}\\
$$

Am I on the right track and understanding the problem statement correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to evaluate $P(T_1\wedge T_2| C)$ This is the probability that it passes both tests given that there is a bug. This is complicated somewhat by the fact that the bug may be in the region that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ have access to.

$T_1$ and $T_2$ each cover half of the program, and they overlap on $50\%$ of the code that they cover. This means that $T_1\cap T_2$ is half of the size of $T_1,$ so it is $1/4$ of the code. Thus $T_1\cup T_2$ is $3/4$ of the code, $1/4$ belonging to $T_1$ alone, $1/4$ belonging to $T_2$ alone, and $1/4$ shared.

So if there is a bug present, it has a $1/4$ chance of being in each region. If it's in the region only covered by $T_1,$ it has a $50\%$ chance of going undetected, and similarly $70\%$ for the region covered only by $T_2.$ If it is in the common region, it will only fail to be detected if both $T_1$ and $T_2$ miss, so the probability is $50\%*70\% = 35\%.$ If the bug is in the region not covered by any test, there is an $100\%$ chance of it going undetected. Thus the probability of a bug going undetected given that one was there is $$P(T_1\wedge T_2| C) = \frac{1}{4}(50\% + 70\% + 35\% + 100\%) = 63.75\% $$

The probability $P(T_1\wedge T_2 | \lnot C)$ is much easier to compute. It is $1$ since both tests are assumed to surely pass if there are no bugs.

Thus by Bayes $$ P(\lnot C|T_1\wedge T_2) = \frac{P(T_1\wedge T_2 |\lnot C)P(\lnot C)}{P(T_1\wedge T_2 | \lnot C)P(\lnot C)+ P(T_1\wedge T_2 | C)P(C)} = \frac{1*0.8}{1*0.8+0.6375*0.2} = 86.25\%$$